# Prove that $a$ is a prime element of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, principal-ideal-domains, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a PID and $P = (a)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Prove that $a$ is a prime element of $R$.

Since $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, let $x,y \in R$ s.t. $xy \in P = (a).$ (WTS $a \mid x$ or $a\mid y$).
Since, $xy \in P = (a) \Rightarrow x \in (a) \vee y \in (a) \Rightarrow a\mid x \vee a\mid y$. Hence, $a$ is a prime element of $R$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You should probably start with "let $x, y \in R$ be s.t. $xy \mid a$" and show (one line) that this implies $xy \in P$. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: @user73985 Thanks, but I thought since $P$ is a prime ideal, we can write $xy \in P$ from the definition of a prime ideal.

Comment: Remember that what you're trying to prove is "$a$ is a prime element of $R$", that is, "given $x, y \in R$ s.t. $a \mid xy$, then either $a \mid x$ or $a \mid y$".

Comment: Clearer: directly translate $\ (p)\supseteq (ab) \,\Rightarrow\, (p)\supseteq (a)\,$ or $\,(p)\supseteq (b)\,$ using $\, (x)\supseteq (y)\iff x\mid y,\,$ i.e. divides = contains for principal ideals

Comment: @user , in first coment , it shoud $a|xy$ ??

Comment: @Sara yes, sorry

Answer (score 0):

After making the prefix mentioned in the comments, you have a fine proof.

The reason why we need to change the assumption to "Let $x,y\in R$ such that $xy|a$" is that as currently worded, you slightly miss the actual question. You're only proving that $xy\in(a)\Rightarrow a|x\vee a|y$, whereas you need to prove that $a|xy\Rightarrow a|x\vee a|y$